# Error herencia con clases

Tags: c++, clase, herencia

He creado una clase base llamada numeros y dos clases derivadas, enteros y imaginarios, me da error en los constructores de las clases derivadas. Os dejo por aqui los archivos de cabecera y las implementaciones de la clase base y clases derivadas.

Clase base:

```
#ifndef NUMEROS_H
#define NUMEROS_H
#include <iostream>


class numeros
{
    public:
        numeros(int a, int b);

        virtual int parte_real();
        virtual int parte_imaginaria();
        virtual std::string cadena();




    private:
        int r;
        int i;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,numeros& n);
#endif // NUMEROS_H
```

Implementacion:

```
#include "numeros.h"
#include "imaginarios.h"
#include "enteros.h"
#include <iostream>



 numeros::numeros(int a, int b):r(a),i(b)
 {

 }

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,numeros& n)
{
    out<<n.cadena();
    return out;
}
std::string numeros::cadena()
{
    std::string salida(std::to_string(r));
    salida.append("+");
    salida.append(std::to_string(i));
    salida.append("i");
    return salida;
}
int numeros::parte_real()
{
    return r;

}
int numeros::parte_imaginaria()
{
    return i;

}
```

Clase derivada:

```
#ifndef ENTEROS_H
#define ENTEROS_H
#include"numeros.h"
#include <iostream>


class enteros: public numeros
{
    public:
        enteros(int n);

        virtual int parte_real();
        virtual int parte_imaginaria();
        virtual std::string cadena();






    private:
        int r;
};

#endif // ENTEROS_H
```

Implementacion:

```
#include "enteros.h"
#include "numeros.h"
#include "imaginarios.h"
enteros::enteros(int n):r(n)
{
}
int enteros::parte_real()
{
    return r;
}
int enteros::parte_imaginaria()
{
    return 0;
}
std::string enteros::cadena()
{
    std::string salida(std::to_string(r));
    return salida;
}
```

El error que me sale al ejecutar es:

```
D:\C++\numeros\enteros.cpp|4|error: no matching function for call to 'numeros::numeros()'|
```

Incluyo unicamente una clase derivada ya que las dos son mayormente iguales, obviando las diferencias que tiene que haber,
Se agradece cualquier ayuda, muchas gracias a todos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes que otra cosa dire que estoy considerando que **numeros.h** e **imaginarios.h** son lo mismo. En tal caso no voy a mencionar a **numeros.h**  y voy a dar por hecho que solo existen **imaginarios.h** y **enteros.h**. Esto lo digo porque no veo que nos hayas colocado el archivo **numeros.h** y de acuerdo al codigo que muestras tampoco veo la necesidad de otro archivo más.

Diré entonces que para resolver el error, dado que existe una relación de herencia entre los números Imaginarios y los Enteros cuando estas construyendo un numero entero debes invocar al constructor de los Imaginarios.

Es decir en el archivo de implementación de los números enteros el constructor debería quedar como:

```
enteros::enteros(int n): numeros(n,0)
{

}
```

Si te fijas con esto estoy indicando que al construir un entero se esta creando un numero imaginario con su parte imaginaria en 0 apoyandome del constructor que ya esta definido en **imaginarios.h**.

Por otro lado en enteros.h estas indicando los siguientes métodos:

```
virtual int parte_real();
virtual int parte_imaginaria();
```

No los necesitas. No los necesitas porque estos ya fueron definidos en **imaginarios.h** y la clase enteros no tiene necesidad de definirlos otra vez porque no los necesita sobreescribir. El único método que realmente vale la pena de colocar en **enteros.h** además del constructor es cadena() pues ese silo lo estas sobreescribiendo con un comportamiento diferente:

```
virtual std::string cadena();
```

Y como te has de imaginar si no necesitas declarar **parte_real()** y **parte_imaginaria()** en **enteros.h** tampoco tienes necesidad de ponerlos en la implementación de **enteros.h**

Por otro lado en la implementación de **imaginarios.h** no necesitas el include de **enteros.h**.

Espero que esto que te coloco te sirva.
Saludos y suerte en tu examen.

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema es muy sencillo de entender: **no puedes instanciar una clase hija sin llamar a un constructor de la clase base**.

Si el compilador te permitiera hacerlo, podrían quedar variables-miembro de tu clase base **sin inicializar**, derivando en comportamientos ... cuanto menos curiosos.

Ahora bien, en un *detalle* por su parte, el lenguaje estipula que si tu codigo **no llama a un constructor de la clase base, se generará una llamada al constructor sin argumentos**.

Ese es el motivo de tu error: en el constructor de tu clase hija, **no llamas** al constructor de la clase base. Por lo que el compilar *inserta* esa llamada por ti, con lo que el código generado se parece a esto:

```
enteros::enteros( int n ) :
  numeros( ),
  r( n )
{
}
```

Pero como tu clase base `numeros` **no proporciona** ese constructor, se genera el error que ves.

> no matching function for call to 'numeros::numeros()'

Las soluciones son simples:

- Realiza una llamada explícita al constructor que prefieras/necesites de tu clase base.
- Añade un constructor sin argumentos a tu clase base.

Answer (score 1):

El error te indica que la función `numeros::numeros()` no existe. Es decir, el constructor por defecto de la clase `numeros`.

Así que necesitas agregar un constructor sin parámetros a tu clase `numeros`.

---

Por cierto, quizá está no sea la mejor forma de usar herencia y polimorfismo. No parece una herencia natural.

Se supone que en una clase base plasmes funcionalidad común a las clases que heredarán de ella.

Por ejemplo, si tuvieras una clase `Televisor` lo más seguro es que le pondrías una función para encenderlo, apagarlo,  cambiar de canal y subir o bajar el volumen.

Luego puede que quieras agregar una clase `TelevisorInteligente` que también tenga aplicaciones, conexión a internet y demás.

Comment: Hola gracias por la ayuda, ahora lo probare, estoy haciendo esto para probar la herencia ya que tengo examen y no se me ocurren ideas en la que la herencia sea algo mas natural.

Comment: @Alvaro debes tener algo en cuenta. Las clases heredan de otras para **extender** su funcionalidad. En cambio, los reales están contenidos en el conjunto de los complejos. Bajo la lógica de la extensión, los complejos son una extensión de los reales. Sería al revés de lo que lo estás haciendo.